# In Source engine games, when are server.cfg and autoexec.cfg executed?

Tags: source-engine, server-administration

On a dedicated server for Source engine games, there are two "global" configuration files - server.cfg and autoexec.cfg.  Are these files executed at different times? What sort of configurations should go in which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**autoexec.cfg** is automatically executed **once** when the server starts before a map loads

**server.cfg** is automatically executed each time a map loads, including map changes

There's also map specific configs that are named after the map. These are executed last.

You usually want to put all of your server configuration in `server.cfg` so that any setting changes, such as from a `mapname.cfg` file, are reset when the map changes. The `autoexec.cfg` is used for anything that should be done before a map loads, such as `sv_pure` settings.

Also, you can change which file is executed on map change using the `servercfgfile` cvar. This is handy if you want to have different modes on a server, or run multiple servers from the same installation.

Comment: Not true, see http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Server.cfg and http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Autoexec, they're executed at launch.

Comment: Which part of my answer is not true? Autoexec.cfg executes once at launch and server.cfg, by default, executes on every map change. That's the way it works.

Comment: The part where you say that server.cfg, by default, executes on every map change. According to Valve, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

While it might work for servers, `autoexec.cfg` is meant for clients. `server.cfg` only works on the server-side, which is useful since it will only be run if you launch a server (eg a listen server) not when you just join one. `autoexec.cfg` will fire in both cases.

Comment: Will autoexec.cfg fire on mapchange, on joining a server, or only when initially launching the game?

Comment: On launch only. Same goes for server.cfg, but only if run as a dedicated server.

Comment: You can *manually* run autoexec.cfg using 'exec autoexec.cfg' in the Developer console.